# Styling Form Inputs on iOS

Tags: ios, css

I am using this code to style my form elements but on iOS, form elements don't appear like this at all..

```
input[type="email"], 
input[type="text"], 
select {
background:transparent;
width:320px;
text-transform:inherit !important;
letter-spacing: 0.1em !important;
text-indent:5px;
height: 55px;
margin:7px 0 3px 0;
border-radius:0px !important;
border: 1px solid #dcdcdc !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some default styles or something like that on iOS.

I believe you can get rid of those by using

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```